# Additional information on normalization of database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I'm a little bit confused about normalization.

Can someone give a real life example in this database? If that's ok ? Thanks.

> table: account_info
>
> > student_number(PK)
> >
> > student_username
> >
> > student_password
>
> table: student_info
>
> > student_number(PK)
> >
> > student_name
> >
> > student_course
> >
> > student_year
> >
> > student_section
>
> table: student_subject
>
> > student_number(PK)
> >
> > student_subject_1
> >
> > .
> >
> > .
> >
> > .
> >
> > student_subject_10

About foreign key, can I use it in the given tables above?

Where and when is it the best time to use it ?

Comment: What part of normalization are you confused about?

Comment: Maybe you should try a search engine first: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php, http://mycigroup.com/Documents/Academics/DatabaseNormalization.pdf and http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SDM04CD/page_01.htm are just the first three results using Google. They all have good examples, that may answer your question – whatever question this is.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' .. im not just pretty sure if my db design is already normalize, or it still needs to be improve, pretty weird right ?

Comment: The example you posted is not normalized.

Comment: @DanBracuk from the link given by feela,
>Table: student_detail

>>Student ID | Name | Zip

>Table: student_address

>> ZIP | Street | City | state

isn't it the same with

>table: account_info

>>student_number(PK)

>>student_username

>>student_password

>table: student_info

>>student_number(PK)

>>student_name

>>student_course

>>student_year

>>student_section

or i am missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you have questions about normalization, you probably should read up on the subject and then ask specific questions. That said ...

The only thing unnormalized I see about your schema here is the student_subject_1, student_subject_2, etc. One of the rules of First Normal Form is "no repeating groups". That is, nothing that you would use an array or list for in a program. Any time you start numbering fields, you should step back and ask if this is not a repeating group, i.e. an array.

The by-the-book normalized thing to do is to change this to:

```
student_number
subject_index
subject_name
```

The primary key is then student_number + subject_index. Or you could create a synthetic id, like a sequence number.

You then create one record for each subject, and use the index to distinguish them.

If the order doesn't mean anything -- if #2 could just as well have been placed at #3 and #4 at #1 etc -- then I'd most likely go for creating a student_subject_id that's simply a sequence number.

There are many good reasons for doing this.

1. Is 10 subjects the absolute limit that can never ever possibly change? If not, if someday a student comes along who has 11 subjects, then your program will break. I ran into this once where a system had, I think it was 8 slots for "child". I suppose someone said, "Who would ever have more than 8 children?" And then of course someone came along who had 11 children.
2. Suppose you want to search for all the students who are taking some subject, say "Database 101". With one subject per record, that's a simple query:

   select student_number from student_subject where subject = 'Database 101'

(Maybe you want to join on the student_info table to get his name, etc, but that's not important here.)

But with 10 subjects in each record, you'd have to write:

```
select student_number from student_subject where subject_1 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_2 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_3 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_4 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_5 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_6 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_7 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_8 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_9 = 'Database 101'
  or subject_10 = 'Database 101'
```

Not only is that a lot to type, but now there are 10 times as many chances to make a typing mistake. Testing will be less reliable. Suppose you mis-typed the subject name in the test for subject_7. The program could appear to work: It would find students who had this subject for 1, 2, 3, etc, If it so happened that no student in your test had this particular subject as #7, the program would give correct results. I ran into exactly this once: somebody made a record with category_1, category_2, etc (we were putting books in a technical library into categories), then wrote a query in which he made a typing mistake on the test for category_7. In our tests we usually only put in 2 or 3 categories on each book, so it all appeared to work. Then we went to production and, boom, it failed the first time someone had a book with 7 categories.

1. If you have to write these queries that check all 10 fields, then if someday you need to add a field, you have to find every query and update to test #11 also. If you miss one, you'll start getting subtle errors in the program. Oh, I ran into this once too, sort of. We had a db with I think it was 5 of something, and somebody wrote a query where, by mistake, he tested 1, 2, 4, and 5, and just forgot to test #3.
2. If you want to be able to search on subject, you'll need indexes on 10 fields instead of 1. Much more database overhead.

Probably other reasons if I think about it some more.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would like to differentiate from Jay's answer on the normalization...  Break into TWO tables for the student and subjects.

No need in copying the name of the class and it's course over and over for every student, it too should be ONCE, then a bridge (or link) table for each student and course taken.  From this table you could also have a status of pass/fail/grade/withdrawn, etc... or even semester it was taken, etc.

Also, pk/fk columns I try to always suffix with "ID" vs an "_number" which may be more confusing to some

```
Table Courses
courseID  (PK) - auto-increment
course    ex: ENGLISH, SCIENCE, COMPUTERS (or their abbreviated codes ENG-101, SCI-210, CMP-101)
Other     any other description about the individual class -- REGARDLESS of when it was offered


Table StudentCourses
studentcourseid  (PK)
student_number   (FK to student table)
courseID         (FK to course table)
enrollStatus     (enrolled, withdrawn, excused, whatever)
enrollSemester   (ex: SPRING2014, SUMMER2014, but this too could be a lookup table of semesters)
creditHoursEarned  (such as for computing GPA)
```

This is actually a very short simplification of an actual college enrollment system I wrote back in mid-90's and running through about 2005 when I left the organization.

Comment: One of the reasons people have so much trouble with normalization is that most people confuse it with other aspects of database design. Normalization has nothing to do with whether a column name ends with "number" or "id". Normalization has nothing to do with creating new attributes that weren't in the original tables (as "courseID", "studentcourseid", "enrollStatus", "enrollSemester", and "creditHoursEarned").

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', I Agree with you that "ID" vs "Number", but I was only trying to break down one more level from what Jay was presenting.  I didn't think I needed to restate the content of his answer.

Comment: RE separating out the course table: Yes, this is absolutely correct. I didn't get into that because my answer was already very long. Note that there's likely more information about a subject than just its name or catalog number: it probably is associated with some department, has a description, an instructor and room assignment, etc. If so, you do not want to repeat this information for every student taking the class. You want to record it once and point there.

Comment: @Jay, yes and no.  The course itself is generic to the entire institution.  In the system I wrote, I had another table of CourseOfferings that had the courseID, teacherID, semesterID, room, building, and other misc stuff applicable to each time.  You could have the same course offered 4 times in a given day and taught by different instructors, but the underlying course, objectives, category (English, Science, etc) are the same.

Comment: @DRapp Sure. I've never built a course management system, but I'd guess you'd normally have a Course table with things like class name, department, description; and then a Course-offering table with time, room, instructor. Maybe another table that ties together courses required for a particular degree. A table of available classrooms. A table of instructors. Etc.

Comment: @Jay, now you are getting the target of normalization.  Help limit duplication of elements.  There are exceptions in some areas, and you'll see it many times especially with web-based apps where there may be things like counts (likes, dislikes, friends, order counts, etc).  These make sense to retain at appropriate level so select count(*) dont kill your app performance for specialized queries.

Comment: @DRapp Sure. The original question brought up one normalization issue: repeating groups. I had a long answer addressing that, so I avoided getting into the whole redundant data issue. Obviously you and I are cool on this, now we just need to explain to the rest of the world! I have plenty of horror stories on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization rearranges base relations and join dependencies. (Some join dependencies correspond to functional dependencies, determining candidate keys.) We can also while normalizing simultaneously rearrange inclusion dependencies. (Candidate keys and inclusion dependencies determine foreign keys.) So learn the meanings of "join dependency", "functional dependency" and "candidate key". And for your ps, "inclusion dependency". Then give us your applicable JDs, FDs and CKs (and INDs). Otherwise your question is unanswerable.

@others: Normalization involves rearranging schemas so the only JDs are consequences of the CKs. (Informally, getting rid of all the conjuncts in base membership conditions/meanings not of the form "attribute=foo(key)".) (Also, PKs have no formal relational role.) So the guessed meaning of the numerically suffixed attributes has no bearing on normalization, although it's bad design for other reasons (as Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' said).